# Replace value in nested array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, replace, nested

i am new on stackoverflow. I have a question. How do this code more appropiate for value replacement in nested arrays?

For example, i have this array obtained from json file:

```
$json_file = "template.json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_file);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now, i obtain the array $res that contain certain searched value:

```
function array_recursive_search_key_map($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $first_level_key=>$value) {
        if ($needle === $value) {
            return array($first_level_key);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $callback = array_recursive_search_key_map($needle, $value);
            if ($callback) {
                return array_merge(array($first_level_key), $callback);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$res = array_recursive_search_key_map("id|logo", $array);
```

Doing this, $res contains the position of the searched value in nested $array:

```
$res = ["content",0,"elements",0,"elements",0,"elements",0,"elements",0,"settings","_attributes"]
```

I want to replace progamatically the value in:

```
$array["content"][0]["elements"][0]["elements"][0]["elements"][0]["elements"][0]["settings"]["_attributes"] = "some new value";
```

I was created a new function but i think are not very practically:

```
function recursive_replacement($keymap, $newvalue)
{
    $size = sizeof($keymap);
    switch ($size)
    {
        case 1:
            $array[$keymap[0]] = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 2:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]] = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 3:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]] = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 4:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]] = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 5:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]][$keymap[4]] = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 6:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]][$keymap[4]][$keymap[5]] = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 7:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]][$keymap[4]][$keymap[5]][$keymap[6]]  = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 8:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]][$keymap[4]][$keymap[5]][$keymap[6]][$keymap[7]]  = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 9:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]][$keymap[4]][$keymap[5]][$keymap[6]][$keymap[7]][$keymap[8]]  = $newvalue;
            break;
        case 10:
            $array[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]][$keymap[4]][$keymap[5]][$keymap[6]][$keymap[7]][$keymap[8]][$keymap[9]]   = $newvalue;
            break;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

And the use way:

```
$new_array = recursive_replacement($res, "some new value");
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good idea to show a sample input structure literal. We don't know what `template.json` has.

Answer (score 0):

At the very first step we need a notation to address an item in an array, i like the dot notation

```php
$array = [
    'item_1' => [
        'item_2' => 1,
        'item_3' => [
            'item_4',
            'item_5'
        ]
    ]
];
```

For example  'item_1.item_3.0' instead of $array['item_1']['item_3'][0]

Now we need to iterate on our address key and find destination element

```php
function  replaceArrayItem($searchKey, $replacement, $array) {
    $itemAddressBlocks = explode('.', $searchKey); // convert to array so we can iterate on address
    
    $replacedArray = $array;
    $temp = &$replacedArray; // pass by reference

    foreach($itemAddressBlocks as $depth => $index) {
        if( $depth < sizeof($itemAddressBlocks) - 1 ) {  // rolling in the deep :)
            $temp = &$temp[$index];  
            continue;
        }
        
        $temp[$index] = $replacement;  // last step and replacement
    }
    
    return $replacedArray;
}
```

Now lets test our new function

```php
/**
Array
(
    [item_1] => ***replacedItem***
)
**/
print_r( replaceArrayItem('item_1', 'replacedItem', $array) );

/**
Array
(
    [item_1] => Array
        (
            [item_2] => ***replacedItem***
            [item_3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => item_4
                    [1] => item_5
                )

        )

)
**/
print_r( replaceArrayItem('item_1.item_2', 'replacedItem', $array) );


/**
Array
(
    [item_1] => Array
        (
            [item_2] => 1
            [item_3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => item_4
                    [1] => ***replacedItem***
                )

        )

)


**/
print_r( replaceArrayItem('item_1.item_3.1', 'replacedItem', $array) );
```

Now You can progamatically

```php
$itemAddress = 'content.0';
for($i =0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $itemAddress .= '.elements.0';
}
$itemAddress .= '.settings._attributes';

replaceArrayItem($itemAddress, $yourValue, $array);
```